# Retrieving background page's AMD module from foreground

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, requirejs

I have an extension which consists of a foreground page and a background page. The background is persistent and contains some models. The foreground is short-lived and contains the views. As such, the foreground's views maintain their state by reading from the persistent background models.

Inside of an extension, one can interact with the background page through [chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage()](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/extension.html) which provides a reference to the background's window.

I am using RequireJS to modularize my javascript. As such, the declaration of a model looks like:

```
//  Exposed globally so that Chrome Extension's foreground can access through chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage()
var VideoDisplayButton = null;

define(function () {
    'use strict';

    var videoDisplayButtonModel = Backbone.Model.extend({

        defaults: {
            enabled: false
        },

        toggleEnabled: function () {
            this.set('enabled', !this.get('enabled'));
        }

    });

    VideoDisplayButton = new videoDisplayButtonModel;

    return VideoDisplayButton;
});
```

and its view counter-part:

```
this.videoDisplayButtonView = new VideoDisplayButtonView({
    model: chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage().VideoDisplayButton
});
```

I am forced to break my AMD module in order for the foreground to be able to successfully reference the instance of my model hosted on the background page.

Ideally, I would like my background's model declaration to be:

```
define(function () {
    'use strict';

    var VideoDisplayButton = Backbone.Model.extend({

        defaults: {
            enabled: false
        },

        toggleEnabled: function () {
            this.set('enabled', !this.get('enabled'));
        }

    });

    return VideoDisplayButton;
});
```

Is this a hard limitation of working with AMD modules inside of a Chrome extension? Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

```
You can pass you model VideoDisplayButton to view VideoDisplayButtonView.
In your background page/view, give the file reference in the define as follows:
define([
  'path-to-VideoDisplayButton-model-file'
],function(VideoDisplayButton){
  var new_model = new VideoDisplayButton();
  this.videoDisplayButtonView = new VideoDisplayButtonView({
    model: new_model
  });
});

Your model should be as follows:
define(function () {
    'use strict';

    var VideoDisplayButton = Backbone.Model.extend({

        defaults: {
            enabled: false
        },

        toggleEnabled: function () {
            this.set('enabled', !this.get('enabled'));
        },

        initialize: function(){
        }

    });

    return VideoDisplayButton;
});
```

Comment: If I reference a module instantiated on the background page from the foreground by its path -- I will get a NEW instance of the module. This is because the foreground is its own, separate page. RequireJS is unaware that the module was loaded on the background page.